# sending traps from a Java application

Tags: java, snmp

What is the quickest simplest way to send a trap from a Java application?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [SNMP4J](http://www.snmp4j.org/) for this.

[This](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/Snmp.html) javadoc might help you write your code. You can use the [Snmp.trap()](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/Snmp.html#trap%28org.snmp4j.PDUv1,%20org.snmp4j.Target%29) method