# Send trap v2 in Java

Tags: java, snmp, snmp-trap

How can I send snmpv2 traps from Java application. I tried  to do example on snmp4j, but it didn't work.

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329378/sending-traps-from-a-java-application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [SNMP4J](http://www.snmp4j.org/) for this.

[This](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/Snmp.html) javadoc might help you write your code. You can use the [Snmp.trap()](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/Snmp.html#trap%28org.snmp4j.PDUv1,%20org.snmp4j.Target%29) method

**Edit:**

Well, I dont have code of my own at this moment, but you may refer [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/snmp4j@agentpp.org/msg01158.html) one . You have to use Snmp.notify() for sending V2 trap instead of Snmp.trap() as trap() only supports sending V1 traps.

Answer (score 21):

It took me some time but I finally figured out how to use SNMP4J to send a trap: Hope that helps..

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      // Create PDU           
      PDU trap = new PDU();
      trap.setType(PDU.TRAP);

      OID oid = new OID("1.2.3.4.5");
      trap.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID, oid));
      trap.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysUpTime, new TimeTicks(5000))); // put your uptime here
      trap.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysDescr, new OctetString("System Description"))); 

      //Add Payload
      Variable var = new OctetString("some string");          
      trap.add(new VariableBinding(oid, var));          

      // Specify receiver
      Address targetaddress = new UdpAddress("10.101.21.32/162");
      CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
      target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
      target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
      target.setAddress(targetaddress);

      // Send
      Snmp snmp = new Snmp(new DefaultUdpTransportMapping());
      snmp.send(trap, target, null, null);                      
}
```

Comment: @Matthieu [`sysUpTime` is](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3416#section-4.2.6); don't know why hannes put `sysDescr` in there though. The `snmpTrapOID` is in the wrong place too and [order matters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7040465/560648).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks for pointing it out (sysUpTime should be first, followed by trapOID). I guess the overwhelming amount of RFCs involved in SNMP gives a great space for books to be written, and questions to be asked!

Comment: @Matthieu No probs, and yes indeed! Trouble is, many (most?) implementations are broken/wrong/non-compliant so even if _you_ get it right, you can't assume that anybody else has!

Answer (score 5):

A good example that sends trap V1 and notification V2. I just needed to modify the port to 162 and the way to set the sysUpTime for both version V1 and V2.

Tested with snmp4j-1.10.1 and snmp4j-2.1.0.

http://www.techdive.in/snmp/snmp4j-trap-sender

```
package snippet;

/**
 * Copyright 2010 TechDive.in
 *  
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * <a href="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0" title="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0">http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</a>
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.  
 *  
 */

/**
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE AUTHOR AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS''
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
 * TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR OR CONTRIBUTORS
 * BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

import java.util.Date;

import org.snmp4j.CommunityTarget;
import org.snmp4j.PDU;
import org.snmp4j.PDUv1;
import org.snmp4j.Snmp;
import org.snmp4j.TransportMapping;
import org.snmp4j.mp.SnmpConstants;
import org.snmp4j.smi.IpAddress;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OID;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OctetString;
import org.snmp4j.smi.UdpAddress;
import org.snmp4j.smi.TimeTicks;
import org.snmp4j.smi.VariableBinding;
import org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping;

public class TrapSender {
    public static final String community = "public";

    // Sending Trap for sysLocation of RFC1213
    public static final String trapOid = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6";

    public static final String ipAddress = "192.168.1.52";

    public static final int port = 162;

    public TrapSender() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrapSender snmp4JTrap = new TrapSender();

        /* Sending V1 Trap */
        snmp4JTrap.sendSnmpV1Trap();

        /* Sending V2 Trap */
        snmp4JTrap.sendSnmpV2Trap();
    }

    /**
     * This methods sends the V1 trap to the Localhost in port 163
     */
    public void sendSnmpV1Trap() {
        try {
            // Create Transport Mapping
            TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
            transport.listen();

            // Create Target
            CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
            comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
            comtarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version1);
            comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress(ipAddress + "/" + port));
            comtarget.setRetries(2);
            comtarget.setTimeout(5000);

            // Create PDU for V1
            PDUv1 pdu = new PDUv1();
            pdu.setType(PDU.V1TRAP);
            pdu.setEnterprise(new OID(trapOid));
            pdu.setGenericTrap(PDUv1.ENTERPRISE_SPECIFIC);
            pdu.setSpecificTrap(1);
            pdu.setAgentAddress(new IpAddress(ipAddress));
                    long sysUpTime = 111111;
        pdu.setTimestamp(sysUpTime);

            // Send the PDU
            Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
            System.out.println("Sending V1 Trap to " + ipAddress + " on Port " + port);
            snmp.send(pdu, comtarget);
            snmp.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error in Sending V1 Trap to " + ipAddress + " on Port " + port);
            System.err.println("Exception Message = " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This methods sends the V2 trap to the Localhost in port 163
     */
    public void sendSnmpV2Trap() {
        try {
            // Create Transport Mapping
            TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
            transport.listen();

            // Create Target
            CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
            comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
            comtarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
            comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress(ipAddress + "/" + port));
            comtarget.setRetries(2);
            comtarget.setTimeout(5000);

            // Create PDU for V2
            PDU pdu = new PDU();

            // need to specify the system up time
                    long sysUpTime = 111111;
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysUpTime, new TimeTicks(sysUpTime)));
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID, new OID(trapOid)));
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapAddress, new IpAddress(ipAddress)));

            // variable binding for Enterprise Specific objects, Severity (should be defined in MIB file)
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(trapOid), new OctetString("Major")));
            pdu.setType(PDU.NOTIFICATION);

            // Send the PDU
            Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
            System.out.println("Sending V2 Trap to " + ipAddress + " on Port " + port);
            snmp.send(pdu, comtarget);
            snmp.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error in Sending V2 Trap to " + ipAddress + " on Port " + port);
            System.err.println("Exception Message = " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @durron597 So what happens if the link dies? Pasting the code is a  good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for snmp4j library http://www.snmp4j.org/.

```
import org.snmp4j.*; 
import org.snmp4j.event.*;

...
CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget(); 
target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public")); 
target.setAddress(targetAddress); 
target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c); 

PDU request = new PDU(); 
request.setType(PDU.V2TRAP); 
request.setGenericTrap(PDUv2.COLDSTART); 

Snmp snmp = new Snmp(new DefaultUdpTransportMapping()); 
snmp.listen(); 
snmp.sendPDU(request, target, null, listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

A very good example can be found here:

http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/snmp/create-snmp-client-in-java-using-snmp4j/

Comment: But not an example of sending a trap.